# Looking for proof for variant of the Barratt-Whitehead lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

$\require{AMScd}$Consider the $3×3$ commutative diagram with exact rows and columns:

$$\begin{CD}
@.@.0@.0@.0@.@.\\
@.@.@VVV@VVV@VVV@.@.\\
@.0@>>>X@>a>>X'@>a'>>X''@>>>0@.\\
@.@.@VfVV@Vf'VV@Vf''VV@.@.\\
@.0@>>>Y@>b>>Y'@>b'>>Y''@>>>0@.\\
@.@.@VgVV@Vg'VV@Vg''VV@.@.\\
@.0@>>>Z@>c>>Z'@>c'>>Z''@>>>0@.\\
@.@.@VVV@VVV@VVV@.@.\\
@.@.0@.0@.0@.@.
\end{CD}$$

I was wondering if there exists an exact map $0\to X\xrightarrow{\alpha}X'\oplus Y\xrightarrow{\beta} Y'\xrightarrow{\gamma}Y''\oplus Z'\xrightarrow{\delta} Z''\to 0$ where $\alpha(x)=(a(x),f(x))$, $\beta(x',y)=f'(x')-b(y)$, $\gamma(y')=(b'(y'),g'(y'))$ and $\delta(y'',z')=g''(y'')-c'(z')$. $Im(\alpha)\subseteq Ker(\beta)$ and $Im(\gamma)\subseteq Ker(\delta)$ are immediate but I can't see $Im(\beta)\subseteq Ker(\gamma)$. Can it be done through diagram-chasing and is there anywhere I could find a proof?

Comment: Here it is is mathjax, not LaTeX. You can embed an image in your text.

Comment: MathJax follows a different syntax to include macros, i.e. `\require{<macro>}`, and the name for commutative diagrams is `AMScd`.

Comment: @Saad I saw your edit, thank you.

Comment: Note that $\ker(\gamma)=\ker(b')\cap\ker(g')$ and $\operatorname{im}(\beta)=\operatorname{im}(b)+\operatorname{im}(f')$.

Comment: @FabioLucchini I was thinking about this wrong- I see it can't be done this way- thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $X’=X’’=Y’=Y’’=\mathbb{Z}$, with identity maps between them, and all other objects zero:

$\require{AMScd}$

$$\begin{CD}
@.@.0@.0@.0@.@.\\
@.@.@VVV@VVV@VVV@.@.\\
@.0@>>>0@>>>\mathbb{Z}@=\mathbb{Z}@>>>0@.\\
@.@.@VVV@|@|@.@.\\
@.0@>>>0@>>>\mathbb{Z}@=\mathbb{Z}@>>>0@.\\
@.@.@VVV@VVV@VVV@.@.\\
@.0@>>>0@>>>0@>>>0@>>>0@.\\
@.@.@VVV@VVV@VVV@.@.\\
@.@.0@.0@.0@.@.
\end{CD}$$

In fact, if $X''\neq0$ then the sequence is never exact, as $\gamma\beta\neq0$. For if $0\neq x''\in X''$, then $x''=a'(x')$ for some $x'\in X'$, and $f''(x'')\neq0$ since $f''$ is a monomorphism. So $\gamma\beta(x',0)=f'(x')$, which is nonzero since $b'f'(x')=f''a'(x')=f''(x'')\neq0$. [I'm assuming that the diagram is a diagram of abelian groups or modules, but the same conclusion will hold in any abelian category.]

Similarly, if $Z\neq0$ then the sequence cannot be exact.

However, there is an exact sequence with $X''\oplus Y'\oplus Z$ as the middle term in place of $Y'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see my construction is wrong now. I also see there is an exact sequence through $X''\otimes Y'\otimes Z$ but what I want is a sequence through $Y'$. If I go through $X''\otimes Y'\otimes Z$ then I can't just project onto $Y'$ and continue, it won't be exact. So is such an exact sequence (ie of the form $X\to X'\otimes Y\to ...\to Y'\to ...\to Z''$) possible ?

Comment: In the example I gave, $0\to X\rightarrow X'\oplus Y\rightarrow Y'\rightarrow Y''\oplus Z'\rightarrow Z''\to 0$ looks like $0\rightarrow0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0\rightarrow0$, and it's easy to check that there is no exact sequence of this form.

Comment: I see- thank you for the help. I was adamant because I actually found this puzzle in an [old assignment](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-905-algebraic-topology-i-fall-2016/assignments/MIT18_905F16_pset6.pdf) online so I was certain it could be done. Cheers.

Comment: If it's question 26 you're referring to, I think you may have misread the question?

Comment: It says "construct two SESs and splice them together". Isn't that equivalent to what I was trying to get, a sequence of the form $0\to X\to X'\otimes Y\to ...\to Y'\to ...\to Z''\to 0$ ?

Comment: What the question asks for is a length four exact sequence: $0\to X\rightarrow X'\oplus Y\rightarrow Y'\rightarrow Y''\to0$ (when translated into your notation), not the length five sequence in your question. Splicing two short exact sequences $0\to A\to B\to C\to0$ and $0\to C\to D\to E\to0$ will give a length four exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to D\to E\to0$.

Comment: This was just my attempt to get the result: in $0\to X\xrightarrow{\alpha}X'\oplus Y\xrightarrow{\beta} Y'\xrightarrow{\gamma}Y''\oplus Z'\xrightarrow{\delta} Z''\to 0$ I would just redefine $\gamma\circ\delta$ as $\chi$ and get the desired sequence $0\to X\xrightarrow{\alpha}X'\oplus Y\xrightarrow{\beta} Y'\xrightarrow{\chi} Z''\to 0$ since "splicing SESs" seems to be merely a suggestion. (Though I now know this doesn't work). I now get that we need: $0\to X\to X'\oplus Y\to ?\to 0$, $0\to ?\to Y'\to Z'$, though I still fail to see what $?$ should be. Sorry for dragging this.

Comment: @chb Taking $\chi:Y'\to Z''$ to be the composition of two arrows in the original diagram, the result can be proved directly by diagram chasing. But I'm afraid that I don't see what was intended by the suggestion to prove it by splicing two short exact sequences.

Comment: I tried the sequence $0\to X\xrightarrow{\alpha}X'\oplus Y\xrightarrow{\beta}Y'\xrightarrow{\chi}Z''\to 0$ with $\chi=\gamma\circ\delta$: I got $Im(\alpha)=Ker(\beta)$ and $Im(\beta)\subseteq Ker(\chi)$ but I can't get the reverse inclusion $Ker(\chi)\subseteq Im(\beta)$. Take $y'\in Ker(\psi)$ st $g''b'(y')=c'g'(y')$... then I'm not certain how to proceed.

Comment: @chb If you’re referring to the $\gamma$ and $\delta$ that you define in the question, then the composition of them is zero. Instead, take $\chi=g’’b’=c’b’$.

Comment: Yes that works just fine. Thanks a lot for your help and patience.